# XML generation with FOR XML Auto

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2000

Consider this query in SQL Server 2000 returning XML.

```
select * from Mytable employee for xml auto , elements
```

I'm trying to create an XML file using classic ASP.

The results of the query is fetched using a recordset object. Tresult is one row and one column.

The resulting xml file has only first 2 row or 255 characters.

How do i make this unlimited?
Is there a way to obtain XML in multirow format from SQL Server 2000?

Here's the asp code

```
dim sql dim rs
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment;filename="& filename

set rs = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")

sql = "select * from Mytable employee for xml auto , elements"

set rs = con.execute(sql)

response.write "<?xml version=""1.0""?>"

response.write rs(0)
```

Comment: Could you post the snippet of classic ASP code that makes the call to SQL Server?

Comment: Can you test what happens if you `select cast((select * from MyTable for xml auto , elements) as varchar(8000))` ?

Comment: it doesn't work Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0):

change your sql to

```
sql = "select * from Mytable employee for xml auto , TYPE, elements"
```